# MySQL Server Sparks up to 400% Please help!

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

Please I need help, my server spec is 6 cores and 16gb ram on a Vps plan, and my sql is giving a lot of problem. somethings it spark up to 400%.

I have tried to configure it many times but it will later spark up again after a day or two. I am using mariaDB currently and running a wp site on the server and database size of 1.7GB.

below is my current my.cnf config.

```
# This group is read both both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

[mysqld]
log-error=/var/lib/mysql/vmi195666.contaboserver.net.err
#slow_query_log=1
performance_schema = ON
#default-storage-engine=MyISAM
#max_allowed_packet=268435456
max_allowed_packet      = 32M
#open_files_limit=10000
symbolic-links=0


skip-name-resolve=1
#skip-external-locking
#key_buffer_size = 2G
#table_open_cache = 4192
#join_buffer_size = 256M
#sort_buffer_size = 8M
#read_buffer_size = 8M
#read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 16M
query_cache_type = 0
#query_cache_limit = 4M
query_cache_size = 0


expire_logs_days=5  # from 0 for limited historical logs
key_cache_age_threshold=64800  # from 300 seconds discard to RD again
key_cache_division_limit=50  # for HOT and WARM usage boundary
key_cache_block_size=16384

#thread_concurrency = 8
#thread_cache_size = 100
tmp_table_size = 88M
max_heap_table_size = 88M


innodb_buffer_pool_size = 7G # (adjust value here, 50%-70% of total RAM)
innodb_log_file_size = 960M
innodb_log_files_in_group = 2

innodb_lru_scan_depth=100
log_warnings=2
max_connect_errors=100
#have_symlink=NO
innodb_purge_threads=4
innodb_read_io_threads=64
innodb_write_io_threads=64
innodb_thread_concurrency=0


innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 7
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1 # may change to 2 or 0
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT

max_connections=400
#max_user_connections=30
#wait_timeout=40
#interactive_timeout=10
#long_query_time=5
```

Here is my MySQLTuner Report

```
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.7.10 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.com/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.2.17-MariaDB
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Log file: /var/lib/mysql/vmi195666.contaboserver.net.err(11M)
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/vmi195666.contaboserver.net.err exists
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/vmi195666.contaboserver.net.err is readable.
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/vmi195666.contaboserver.net.err is not empty
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/vmi195666.contaboserver.net.err is smaller than 32 Mb
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/vmi195666.contaboserver.net.err contains 69921 warning(s).
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/vmi195666.contaboserver.net.err contains 89 error(s).
[--] 25 start(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/vmi195666.contaboserver.net.err
[--] 1) 2018-10-29 15:40:13 140332307847360 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 2) 2018-10-22 14:11:57 140273926736064 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 3) 2018-10-21  4:45:56 139694061492416 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 4) 2018-10-20 21:58:09 139845201819840 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 5) 2018-10-05  6:53:08 139745408678080 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 6) 2018-10-05  4:28:22 140625873856704 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 7) 2018-09-27 17:05:37 139928907647168 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 8) 2018-09-18 10:17:05 140013707499712 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 9) 2018-09-14  9:25:29 140178830198976 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 10) 2018-09-09 23:12:45 140288578197696 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
[--] 15 shutdown(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/vmi195666.contaboserver.net.err
[--] 1) 2018-09-18 12:04:37 140170985395968 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 2) 2018-09-09 23:12:43 140009693865728 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 3) 2018-09-09 23:11:36 140024525231872 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 4) 2018-09-09 23:10:42 139645632177920 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 5) 2018-09-09 23:05:23 140597407938304 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 6) 2018-09-09 22:51:00 139671733114624 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 7) 2018-09-09 22:47:41 140515561195264 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 8) 2018-09-09 22:46:17 139697642653440 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 9) 2018-09-09 22:32:11 140358903416576 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
[--] 10) 2018-09-09 22:26:34 139953054557952 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA +SEQUENCE
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 1.4M (Tables: 32)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 1.7G (Tables: 54)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[!!] User 'root@localhost' has no password set.
[!!] User 'oybqgroy_wp@%' does not specify hostname restrictions.
[!!] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 9h 19m 59s (3M q [117.155 qps], 38K conn, TX: 10G, RX: 4G)
[--] Reads / Writes: 93% / 7%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 15.5G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 8.9G
[--] Other process memory: 2.4G
[--] Total buffers: 7.4G global + 2.9M per thread (400 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 445M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 7.9G (50.62% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 8.9G (57.52% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/3M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 5% (23/400)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.60%  (228/38171)
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (5 temp sorts / 242K sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 55% (99K on disk / 177K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (28 created / 38K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 96% (247 open / 256 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (104/10K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (17K immediate / 17K locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 445.5M
[--] Sys schema is installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 6 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (10.2.17-MariaDB)

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 1.5% (2M used / 134M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/329.0K
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 99.5% (4K cached / 21 reads)
[OK] Write Key buffer hit rate: 98.2% (899 cached / 883 writes)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 7.0G/1.7G
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 960.0M * 2/7.0G should be equal 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 7
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 56 for 7 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 100.00% (5317874677 hits/ 5317948865 total)
[OK] InnoDB Write log efficiency: 91.21% (940961 hits/ 1031677 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 90716 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/1B
[!!] Aria pagecache hit rate: 94.1% (1M cached / 98K reads)

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- RocksDB Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] RocksDB is disabled.

-------- Spider Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Spider is disabled.

-------- Connect Metrics ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Connect is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: MIXED
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: Not Activated
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: Not Activated
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/vmi195666.contaboserver.net.err file
    Control error line(s) into /var/lib/mysql/vmi195666.contaboserver.net.err file
    Set up a Password for user with the following SQL statement ( SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'SpecificDNSorIp' = PASSWORD('secure_password'); )
    Restrict Host for user@% to user@SpecificDNSorIp
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    When making adjustments, make tmp_table_size/max_heap_table_size equal
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries which have no LIMIT clause
Variables to adjust:
    tmp_table_size (> 88M)
    max_heap_table_size (> 88M)
```

Comment: You cannot "tune your way out of a performance problem".  Let's see one or two of the slowest queries, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table(s) they use.  The solution may be as simple as adding a 'composite' index.

Comment: **https://pastebin.com/raw/ePnB6DtU**   That is the tables and slow query. my most problems comes from search and tags of the site.

Comment: If you have 6 cores, then 400% CPU is only 66% utilization.  There is not *necessarily* anything wrong with this.

Comment: Possibly only 4 connections, but all are running full tilt.  Note:  One MySQL connection can use only one core.

Comment: @GodwinAlexOgbonda Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
E) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device and cpu/core count, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis and my.cnf suggestions will be offered.

Comment: @Wilson Hauck here is the pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/raw/7AJapw5U

HERE IS MY htop command screenshot https://goo.gl/Sq9Pjw

the _SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; _ displays _#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation_ when I try to run it via phpmyadmin so I ran it via ssh and it worked fine. check the pastebin link for the results

Comment: Thanks for the recent posts, still need results from OS of A) ulimit -a for a linux/unix list of limits, B) iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device and cpu/core count, C) df -h for a linux/unix free space list by device, for server tuning analysis and my.cnf suggestions will be offered. Also, at www.mysqlservertuning.com you will find Utility Scripts+ that includes find-redundant-indexes.sql - findfragtables.sql - globalstatusage10sec.sql available as FREE downloads.  Login with your existing account for checkout, please.

Comment: @Wilson Hauck HERE is the link https://goo.gl/DQSu7M https://goo.gl/7uPLNw https://goo.gl/9nWZmy to all the things you requested above

Comment: Thank you for the additional requested data.  Hoping to have your analysis completed in next 24 hours with suggestions for you.

Answer (score 2):

(Preliminary review of the pastbin)

There are 13 **identical indexes** like this

```
KEY `post_status` (`post_status`,`post_type`,`post_date`),
```

Similarly for

```
 KEY `autoload` (`autoload`),
```

Is something automatically generating them?  Keep one, `DROP` the others.

**Prefix indexing** is virtually useless:

```
 KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191)),
```

See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes) for 5 workarounds.  Ditto for all the other "prefix indexes" with `(191)`.

**Partial EAV optimization**:  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta) for how to speed up `postmeta` tables.

**Wildcards and `OR`**:  This (and similar constructs) is inefficient:

```
                      OR  (9ja_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%paw%')
                      OR  (9ja_posts.post_content LIKE '%paw%'))
```

because:

- The leading wildcard prevents use of an index
- `OR` prevents the use of an index

Consider having a **FULLTEXT** index on the combination of columns.

**IN ( SELECT )** may not be optimal:

```
NOT IN ( SELECT ... )
```

Better options:  `EXISTS ( SELECT ... )` or `LEFT JOIN .. ON .. IS NULL`

**Pagination via `OFFSET`**, as in

```
ORDER BY ... LIMIT  260, 10
```

is inefficient in multiple ways.  [*This*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) discusses how to "remember where you left off" as a significantly faster way.  (Caveat:  It does not apply in all situations.)

It is rare that I encounter a Question that clearly needs help from 3 of my blogs.  This Question wins the prize.

**Summary**

My 7 bits of advice are mostly independent of each other, and each *may* produce a noticeable improvement.  It would be hard to predict which would give you the most bang for the buck.  (Hmmm... I wonder if '7 tips' is a new record.)

Try to implement much of what I advise here, then (if you still have trouble), come back for more advice.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, but I am not good in database stuff, I followed your previous tips to achieve the my.cnf I posted. Please is there any other way to work this out via config?

Comment: @GodwinAlexOgbonda - My mantra:  "You can't tune your way out of a performance problem."  Start with the ones you think you can handle.  Maybe you will get enough benefit without going to the more difficult ones.

Comment: thanks for ur tips, but right now i cleared all my tags and assign my wp search to only title, and the highest slow query time is "2" since monitoring the server.

But I dont understand the "sleep" on the query via this screenshot https://goo.gl/BxbbLz

the highest the sql can go for now is 242. after I edited my.cnf a bit, I dont know if there is any other way to improve it, because the sql time on the top command growing every time. HERE IS MY TOP COMMAND screenshot https://goo.gl/gz9mSX


HERE IS MY htop command screenshot https://goo.gl/Sq9Pjw

Comment: @GodwinAlexOgbonda - `Sleep` (in `PROCESSLIST)` means that a user is still connected, but not doing any query _at this instant_ (actually in the last N seconds, see "Time").  It _may_ mean that you have "connection pooling" and the 'pooled connection' is idle.  In any case, "Sleep" is "not a problem".

Comment: @GodwinAlexOgbonda - `top` is mostly useless.  "Load average" probably said "4" when you saw "400%" somewhere.  `htop` has a little more detail.  Bug, again, not very useful for MySQL issues.  I prefer `PROCESSLIST` and slowlog for mysql.

Comment: the command `PROCESSLIST` is not working so I used `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` and got the output in the below screenshot

https://goo.gl/L3WRFg https://goo.gl/r7vBNP https://goo.gl/qtmSCD

Comment: @GodwinAlexOgbonda - That output shows essentially nothing going on.  Aside from the Daemons, here are 4 connections: 3 'Sleeping', and 1 is the `SHOW` that you ran to get the output.

Comment: To be sincere after clearing my tag and query to wp search to only title that is the screenshot i provided above, it has dropped for a bit, I rebooted my vps and the highest it could go is 242, and drops back to 50,24 34 and so on, but I am still scared that after a day it will start moving up back to 400% as usual 

For now I have no slow query taking more than 2sec but the sql still goes up.

Answer (score -1):

Suggestions for your OS to increase Open Files availability

ulimit -n 48000   # from current 1024 reported by ulimit -a report

To make this change persistent across OS shutdown/restart review this url

https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/

Your details may be slightly different due to OS version.

Rate Per Second=RPS - 
Suggestions for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_io_capacity=15000  # from 200 to use more of SSD IOPS available
read_rnd_buffer_size=192K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS
innodb_flushing_avg_loops=5  # from 30 to reduce loop delay & history list length
innodb_adaptive_max_sleep_delay=10000  # from 150000 for 1 second delay when busy vs 15 seconds
innodb_buffer_pool_size=3G  # from 7G to support your 1.4G of data with room to grow
open_files_limit=30000  # from 10000 to reduce opened_files RPS
innodb_flush_neighbors=0  # from 1 to conserve CPU cycles since you have SSD
innodb_log_buffer_size=96M  # from 16M to support ~ 30 min in buffer
```

For additional assistance, please view my profile, Network profile for contact info including my Skype ID and get in touch by Skype, please.

The BEST to you and your team.

Comment: After following the above suggestions, it consumes more cpu cores than my previous settings

Comment: is there any difference between `innodb_log_file_size` and `innodb_log_buffer_size` ?

Comment: @GodwinAlexOgbonda  You have 6 cores from what I can tell.  What is the % busy you are seeing now?   The buffer_size is in RAM to store log before writing to innodb_log_file to reduce number of call to OS for the log. You have enough RAM to support the larger innodb_log_buffer_size.  Let's SKYPE, your tomorrow morning, please.

Comment: alright then, it was consuming 4-5 core and the sql was highest was 300+ but sometimes it drops.